# SLF4J Logger does clear console output sometimes (unwantedly)

Tags: java, eclipse, console, slf4j, logback

I am using SLF4J + Logback to output messages to the eclipse IDE console.

```
Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
LOG.debug("test");
```

But sometimes the whole console output gets cleared and i cannot see older messages. Is that enough information so that you can help me out?

Comment: can you copy your logback.xml

Comment: this happens with the default configuration of logback

Comment: Which console?  CMD.EXE window?  IDE console panel?  Java Console?

Comment: Eclipse console. Sorry i missed to point that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you might be hitting the default console output limit in Eclipse. You can edit it under Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console. Either increase the console buffer size (default is 80000 characters) or uncheck the "limit console output" box.

Comment: Not the case. It's cutting messages even after 10 lines, and sometimes after 100. I don't see a pattern there. And it is not cutting the first messages, it empties the whole output sometimes and then continues.

Comment: Does it happen on the command line as well? You might want to include your logging configuration in the question, someone might be able to point something out.